# Why bdev_get_queue return NULL?

Tags: linux-kernel, block-device

I developing a "filter" for block device (Linux, Ubuntu 16), 
during initialization of the filter-driver I have tried to the **queue** pointer for the backend (existen device), a body of the **bdev_get_queue** macro show cool comment *"this never NULL"*, but I go the NULL for the **bd_disk** field of the **struct block_device**.

What I'm need to check additionally?

```
static int __init dua_init(void)
{
    int status;
    struct request_queue *backend_queue = NULL;
    struct super_block *sb = NULL;

    printk(KERN_NOTICE __MODULE__ ": Initialize the driver ...\n");

    if ( IS_ERR(backend_bdev = lookup_bdev(dudrv_bckend, FMODE_READ)) )
        {
        status = PTR_ERR(backend_bdev);
        printk(KERN_ERR __MODULE__ ": lookup_bdev(%s) -> %d\n", dudrv_bckend, status);
        return  status;
        }

    $DELAY(1);

    if ( sb = freeze_bdev(backend_bdev) )
        $TRACE(": freeze I/O on block device %s ...", dudrv_bckend);

    $DELAY(1);

    $TRACE(" %p ", backend_bdev->bd_disk);

    $DELAY(1);

    backend_queue = bdev_get_queue(backend_bdev);

    $TRACE(" -- ");

    $DELAY(1);

    if ( backend_make_request_fn != backend_queue->make_request_fn )
        {
        backend_make_request_fn = backend_queue->make_request_fn;
        backend_queue->make_request_fn = dua_make_request_fn;

        $TRACE(": Change for %s request_fn = %p -> %p, ", dudrv_bckend, backend_make_request_fn, backend_queue->make_request_fn);
        }
    else    {
        printk(KERN_NOTICE __MODULE__ ": I/O request process has been set.\n");
        }

    $TRACE(" -- ");

    /* unlock filesystem */
    $DELAY(1);
    if ( sb )
        if (status = thaw_bdev(backend_bdev, sb))
            printk(KERN_NOTICE __MODULE__ ": thaw_bdev() -> %d\n", status);

    printk(KERN_NOTICE __MODULE__ ": End the driver initialization.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Update1: what is the difference between queue's pointer is supposed to be returned by the **bdev_get_queue** and *struct block_device.**bd_queue*** ?

Comment: Provide the code.

Comment: Add code into the **question post**. After inserting the code, select it and press Ctrl+K or "{}" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lookup_bdev() don't create a full Block I/O context.